# How the users can send each others payment in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, paypal

My app is a multi vendor app, here the users will sell and buy each other's products, I need to integrate the paypal payment in my app, I have tried a code in which a user can send money in an account(the account whose client id and secret key I have defined in the app) but I need something where users can send money to each other. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users can send payment using each other's email id without needing of client id and secret key. You can use the **flutter_inappwebview** flutter package for paypal payment integration. Moreover you can also create your own php code. I have found an article on paypal payment integration in php, here is the link:
https://phppot.com/php/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-php/
 you can put this code on your server and access it in your app using flutter_inappwebview package.